# Apache Spark distribute multiple .DAT files to workers

Tags: python, file, apache-spark

I am new to Apache Spark and I want to distribute .DAT files to workers in my cluster so each of the workers process different files. I put my 4 files on a shared disk. My cluster has 1 master and 2 workers. I want to achieve that each of the workers process 2 of these files. So I tried this:

```
def my_func(file_to_process):
    # do something with file
    return x, y

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster(mySparkMasterUrl)
conf.setAppName('Simple app')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

files_to_process = ['s:/file1.DAT', 's:/file2.DAT', 's:/file3.DAT', 's:/file4.DAT']
dist_files_to_process = sc.parallelize(files_to_process)
processed = dist_files_to_process.map(lambda file: my_func(file))
collected = processed.collect()
```

So for example worker1 would process file1.DAT and file2.DAT and at the same time worker2 would process file3.DAT and file4.DAT. But what happens is that one worker process all the files and the second one is not doing anything. Any help or ideas please?

Comment: When you do sc.parallelize, how many partitions does the RDD exist in?  Maybe try specifying the partition number as 2?

Comment: @mrwyatt yes I tried to explicitly specify the number of partitions to 2 already, but nothing changes.